# Unable to fetch the value of a class

Tags: jquery

On click of the plus and minus button , how can i fetch the value of the QtyInput class ??

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function (e) {
    var data = $(this).closest('div').siblings('.QtyInput').text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/16/

```
<div class="Qty_Wrap">
    <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">-</button>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="2" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">+</button>
</div>
<div class="Qty_Wrap">
    <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">-</button>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="5" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">+</button>
</div>
```

could you please help me as how to achive this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.QtyInput` is a child of the parent `div`, so you need to use `find`, not `siblings`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val();
    alert(value);
});

$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val();
    alert(value);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/17/)